# Unable to load to Bigquery from GCS using python. Client has no attribute issue

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to load a file from Google Cloud Storage to Google BigQuery and I am running into some issues:
[image]

This is the code I used (directly copied from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/cloud-client/load_data_from_gcs.py)):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You probably are not using version `0.28`, you can check it by running:

```
pip freeze | grep google-cloud-core
```

This is the [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/1e79287b1c05c678e672f571f2ccdd9c4e5c87bc/bigquery/cloud-client/load_data_from_gcs.py) you probably are looking for (version `0.27`):

```
def load_data_from_gcs(dataset_name, table_name, source):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_name)
    table = dataset.table(table_name)
    job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())

    job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_storage(
        job_name, table, source)

    job.begin()
    job.result()  # Wait for job to complete

    print('Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.'.format(
        job.output_rows, dataset_name, table_name))
```

You can also run `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery` to updated your client but remember before running this that the latest version is backwards incompatible so it can break your whole code.

Comment: if I am on windows, how would I check the current version?

Comment: Is there a way to get nested data into bigquery from GCS with version .28?

Comment: Sure, the sample-docs have plenty of examples showing how to do that. Keep in mind though that you'll have to save results as json files and not csvs as the former has support for nested data.